# Are marker interfaces the best way to specify types?

Tags: java

I have two POJO's which have different properties but are essentially considered to be the same type by another POJO. Hence I added a marker interface and made the two classes implement it.

For eg:

```
interface IMarker {
}

class A implements IMarker {
    String property;
}

class B implements IMarker {
    int property;
}

class C {
    IMarker markerType;
}
```

Now I can set any objects of A or B to C.

Question: Is there any other cleaner way to specify that the type of markerType field in C can only be of type A or B?

Comment: Those don't look like [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) classes.

Comment: *"Is there any other cleaner way to specify that the type of markerType field in C can only be of type A or B?"* - I think the solution is as clean as it can get.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you can't do anything with the variable `markerType` without casting it to one of the implementations. So this is not a great solution. Why not put the common functionality between classes `A` and `B` in the interface? Then you can call that without the need for casting.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use generic type same as this:**

```
class C<T> {

    T property;
    IMarker markerType;
}
```

define A as `C<Integer>`

define B as `C<String>`

**you can define A in function same as :**

```
void func1(C<Integer> a){
  ...
}
```

**you can define B in function same as :**

```
void func2(C<String> b){
  ...
}
```

**you can use A&B in function same as :**

```
void func3(C c){
  ...
}
```